# How to handle Asynchronous call in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous

I have to return the response from the firebase to another function which will do further processing with that data.

```
public ArrayList<String> getDatas(String number) {
    final ArrayList<String> requestList = new ArrayList<>();

    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Users").child(number).child("request_list");

    final DatabaseReference requestReference = database.getReference("Request");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: ");
                for (final DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: data: " + data.getValue());
                    requestList.add(data.getValue().toString());
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: for ended");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    return requestList;
}
```

Since the firebase operation is asynchronous I am not able to wait for the data to return. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Rethink your design. You don't  really want to wait until the data is available.

Comment: So should I notify every time new data is added

Comment: No, just update your UI asynchronously as soon as the data is there.

Comment: Don't ever try to block the main thread for any reason.  That will create a poor experience for your users, and possibly an ANR.  You should become accustomed to the fact that Firebase APIs are all asynchronous, and you'll need to create or update your views after the listener is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a callback method

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

By using Callable interfaces you can pass an argument as function I added a simple code snippet for understanding.

```
public class MainActivity<V> extends Activity {


    Callable<String> doLogin=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        doLogin=new Callable<String>() {  //created but not called now.

            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {

                //make some piece of code
                return "something"; //or false
            }
        };

        CheckSession checkSession=new CheckSession("sessionName");
        String sessionKey="";


        try {  //we are sending callable to the DAO or any class we want 
             sessionKey=checkSession.getSessionKey(doLogin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public class CheckSession{


    String sessionName="";
    Callable<String> func=null;

    public CheckSession(String sessionName) {
        super();
        this.sessionName = sessionName;

    }

    public String getSessionKey(Callable<String> doLogin) throws Exception{

        func=doLogin;

        return (String) func.call();

    }

}
```